# DISTINCT SQL query with inner joins that omits a column from considerations,

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have a DB2 query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RETAILMASTERFILE.DOIDCD AS "RETAILMASTERFILE_DOIDCD",
         RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO AS "RETAILMASTERFILE_COCOMO",
         #XENOS.CUSTREF AS "XENOS_CUSTREF",
         #XENOS.ADDUDT AS "XENOS_ADDUDT",
         #XENOS.ADUPDD AS "XENOS_ADUPDD",
         #XENOS.ADUPDT AS "XENOS_ADUPDT",
         #XENOS.ADSTAT AS "XENOS_ADSTAT"
FROM     RETAILMASTERFILE INNER JOIN
         #XENOS ON RETAILMASTERFILE.DOCOMP = #XENOS.ADCOMP 
                AND RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO = #XENOS.ADDELN 
WHERE     (RETAILMASTERFILE.DOIDCD = 'CUST008') 
      AND (RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO = '345126032') 
      AND (RETAILMASTERFILE.DOCOMP = 'LONDON')
```

The problem is `#XENOS.ADUPDT` may not be unique which gives me an unwanted duplicate record.
Is there any way I can exclude this from consideration ? Everything I've tried so far within my limited knowledge and crude understanding of group by has so far broken my query.

Comment: If there are different #XENOS.ADUPDT, how do chose which one to select?

Comment: @jarlh I'm not too bothered, #XENOS.ADUPDT is just time stamp and any value is pretty much close to the desired time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT   RETAILMASTERFILE.DOIDCD AS "RETAILMASTERFILE_DOIDCD",
         RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO AS "RETAILMASTERFILE_COCOMO",
         #XENOS.CUSTREF AS "XENOS_CUSTREF",
         #XENOS.ADDUDT AS "XENOS_ADDUDT",
         #XENOS.ADUPDD AS "XENOS_ADUPDD",
         MAX(#XENOS.ADUPDT) AS "XENOS_ADUPDT",
         #XENOS.ADSTAT AS "XENOS_ADSTAT"
FROM     RETAILMASTERFILE INNER JOIN
         #XENOS
         ON RETAILMASTERFILE.DOCOMP = #XENOS.ADCOMP AND
            RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO = #XENOS.ADDELN 
WHERE  (RETAILMASTERFILE.DOIDCD = 'CUST008') AND (RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO = '345126032') AND 
       (RETAILMASTERFILE.DOCOMP = 'LONDON')
GROUP BY RETAILMASTERFILE.DOIDCD,
         RETAILMASTERFILE.COCOMO,
         #XENOS.CUSTREF,
         #XENOS.ADDUDT,
         #XENOS.ADUPDD,
         #XENOS.ADSTAT;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to put the group by. I had it before the WHERE statement.